# How to update state machine

Tags: xstate, xstate-react

Is it possible to replace the currently initialized state machine in React?

For example, I initialize a state machine via Provider with a dummy configuration. Then, upon entering a specific page in the app, I update it via context.

Background of what I want to achieve: Consumer can either load the configuration globally or page-specific. Let's say for example that a required data for your config is unknown until you reach a specific portion of your page. So, only then you can properly create a state machine. Or, if consumer wants to keep the configuration per module/page. Bec doing this at the top level would mean, you have to collate all configurations which can get lengthy and hard to debug assuming you know the configuration in advance.

**In provider**

```
const dummyConfig =  {
  id: 'init',
  initial: 'init_state',
  states: {
    init_state: {
      on: {},
    },
  },
};
const initMachine = createMachine(dummyConfig);
const [stateMachine, setStateMachine] = useState(initMachine);

// stateMachine does not get updated with the new machine from the child component below
// passed via setMachine callback in the context
const [current, send, service] = useMachine(stateMachine);

const updateMachine = useCallback((machine: StateMachine) => {
   setStateMachine(machine);
}, []);

return (
    <MachineContext.Provider value={[current, send, service, updateMachine]}>
      {children}
    </StateMachineContext.Provider>
);
```

**In child component somewhere in the app**

```
const machine = createMachine(newConfig);

// Context hook
const { current, send, servicee, updateMachine } = useStateMachine();

// I can receive the new machine up in the provider (checked via console log),
// but it does not update the machine
// The value of current remains that from the first created machine
updateMachine(machine);
```

Comment: It is possible. Note that replacing the state machine can be a complex task and might require a significant change in the application's architecture.

Comment: @shamnadsherief how? any reference that I can look at? I added some context of what I am trying to achieve.